# Pointers in nested struction are not NULL in c

Tags: c

i have this weird output for this piece of code.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct _list1{
    char *str;
    struct _list1 *next;
} list1;

typedef struct struct1{
    char* str;
    list1* l;
}struct1;

typedef struct struct2{
    char* str;
    union{
        struct1 s;
    }extra;
}struct2;


int main()
{

    struct2 *d;
    if(d==NULL){
        printf("d is null\n");
    }else{
        printf("d not null\n");
    }
    d = (struct2*)malloc(sizeof(struct2));
    if(d==NULL){
        printf("d is null\n");
    }else{
        printf("d not null\n");
    }
    if(d->str==NULL){
        printf("d is null\n");
    }else{
        printf("d str not null\n");
    }
    if(((d->extra).s).str==NULL){
        printf("d extra s str is null\n");
    }else{
        printf("d extra s str not null\n");
    }
    if(((d->extra).s).l==NULL){
        printf("d extra s l is null\n");
    }else{
        printf("d extra s l not null\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

results:

```
d not null
d not null
d str not null
d extra s str not null
d extra s l not null
```

why d (pointer) is not null and what don't get is why the header of my list (l) or any one of them are not null after using malloc (even forcing d=NULL before malloc), i mean, i didn't directly allocate memory to the header or to the str pointer.

and when i compile the same code in online c compiler "https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler" i get this results which is complitly different from the one i get using my pc.

```
d is null                                                                                                                                                                                   
d not null                                                                                                                                                                                  
d device type is null                                                                                                                                                                       
d extra s str is null                                                                                                                                                                       
d extra s l is null
```

Comment: `struct2 *d;` declares an *uninitialized* struct pointer. `malloc(sizeof(struct2));` allocates a block of memory for a `struct2`, but that memory is not initialized. (all of the pointers contained in `struct2` remain uninitialized)  If you want to allocate and set all bytes zero, then use `calloc()`, e.g.  `calloc(1, sizeof(struct2));` In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: If you have compiler warnings enabled (which you should), you would have received a warning that `d` was uninitialized, e.g. `"27:7: warning: ‘d’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]"`

Comment: casting the result of malloc is just a habit, and for the initialization part, as far as i know, i don't need to set d=NULL because by default pointer get null if they are not initialized, i do want them to be null. the results from the online compiler looks fine, but the one i get using my home pc, is weird and completely different. i don't get it, why variables in d are not null, how they get initialized?

Comment: The first `if (d == NULL)` invokes *Undefined Behavior* because it access the value of `d` while its value in indeterminate. Fix with `struct2 *d = NULL;`

Comment: that didn't help, it just will force d to get null but the rest of variable will not be null after using malloc.(i have tested this)

Comment: It did help. [C11 Standard - 6.7.9 Initialization(p10)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10) *"If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate."* and [C11 Standard - J.2 Undefined Behavior](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2) "The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.9, 6.8)." -- it won't change the randomness of what you might get with your tests -- that is determined by whatever happens to be in those memory locations to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing first....

Why `d` dynamically alloacated is not null??

Because after dynamic allocation d is pointing to the newly generated memory address by malloc...

2- coming to the other part now if u compile the above program compiler may use default `NULL` initialization or not depending upon the compiler as the same code in my editor provided the same latter result of your GDB compiler...better practice is to intialize the pointer to `NULL` as soon as declared rather than to depend upon compiler to avoid these kind of ambiguity...

example:

```
struct s{
  char *ptr;
};

int main(){
   struct s s1;
   if(s1.ptr == NULL) cout<<1;
}
```

The output from my compiler is 1;

Comment: so you say, it's better to create a function to initialize d (that allocate memory for d and initialize the rest of variable to null or what ever value i want) ??

Comment: Actually yes if u enable that functionality that will be nice but  if u plan to move to c++ we have the feature to default intialize the structre member inside only....

Comment: Note this depending on compiler will be a loss in long run because in larger codes they are the root cause of memory leak so have habit of default null initialization of pointers...